# How to get all user profiles in SharePoint Online/Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile

I want to loop through all user profiles & want to get "Direct Reports" property of users using CSOM C#.

Please help.

Comment: Hello @Visal, could you please check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137385/get-the-list-of-all-users-from-sharepoint-online